# Python - Performing a comparative function on all files in a directory

Tags: python, directory, python-import

I have a function that finds the mean length of a string...

```
 def mean_length(sequence):
    sum = 0.0
    nonblank = 0
    for string in sequence:
        if string.strip():
            sum = sum + len(string)
            nonblank = nonblank + 1
    return sum/nonblank
```

I'm having troubling creating a new function that will find the .txt file in a directory with the highest mean string length compared to all the rest of the .txt files. Any help would be great, particularly how to compare all files in a directory. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
path = # This will be the path to the directory from your current working driectory

import glob
files = glob.glob(path + '*.txt') # This returns a list containing all files that are in the path that end in ".txt"
for file in files:
    # Do what you need to do here for each file
```

https://docs.python.org/2/library/glob.html